# 403 Unauthorized when using Google+ API in Python

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-plus-domains

I'm using this code, mostly extracted from Google samples:

```
"""
did a pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
"""

import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

from environments import get_client_id, get_client_secret

# List the scopes your app requires:
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write']

# The following redirect URI causes Google to return a code to the user's
# browser that they then manually provide to your app to complete the
# OAuth flow.
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# For a breakdown of OAuth for Python, see
# https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth
# CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET come from your API Console project
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=get_client_id(),  # extracted from console.developers.google.com
                           client_secret=get_client_secret(), # extracted from console.developers.google.com
                           scope=SCOPES,
                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

# This command-line server-side flow example requires the user to open the
# authentication URL in their browser to complete the process. In most
# cases, your app will use a browser-based server-side flow and your
# user will not need to copy and paste the authorization code. In this
# type of app, you would be able to skip the next 3 lines.
# You can also look at the client-side and one-time-code flows for other
# options at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/
print('Please paste this URL in your browser to authenticate this program.')
print(auth_uri)
code = input('Enter the code it gives you here: ')

# Set authorized credentials
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

# Create a new authorized API client.
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)

circle_service = service.circles()
request = circle_service.list(userId='me')

while request is not None:
    circle_list = request.execute()

    if circle_list.get('items') is not None:
        print('Google+ circles for the current user: ')
        circles = circle_list.get('items')
        for circle in circles:
            print('\t %s' % circle.get('displayName'))

    request = circle_service.list_next(request, circle_list)
```

You can see I have some functions that return the credentials generated from [Google's developers console](https://console.developers.google.com).

[image: credentials_console_screenshot]

I get the red and *-masked string for client_id and the one client_secret inside the JSON downloaded using the right red download button.

So everything goes OK at first, it opens a windows in Chrome and I consent and paste the code at the command-line, and when coming to this code:

```
request.execute()
```

it shows an error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/madtyn/PycharmProjects/telegram/api_samples/plus/sample_list_circles.py", line 62, in <module>
    circle_list = request.execute()
  File "/home/madtyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/madtyn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 842, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

I did a similar code with the basic G+ API and got it working, but with this I'm stuck.  I don't know where is the error. The only clue I've got is that this import appears as unresolved in PyCharm:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

Any ideas? I can't find where I'm not following the Google API instructions. I keep reading but I've got no clue.

Comment: If you're getting 403, mostly likely you have the api code part working ok, but you aren't passing the right authentication credentials. Or they may be right, but in the wrong form.

Comment: I just noticed and read your comment. How could I know what's wrong? I'm adding a screenshot just in case I'm getting some credential wrong from the Google's console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now pretty sure that this can't be done because G+ API is not being maintained.

I'm accepting this as answer but if anyone does come up with a solution I think I can change the accepted answer so, be my guest.